# SoapHeaderException was unhandled when calling web service

Tags: c#, web-services, exception

An exception occurs on line

```
ModifyProfileResp resp = BFGlobal.modifyProfile(req);
```

> INTERNAL_ERROR, SoapHeaderException was unhandled

```
 Error: System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode -532462766,
```

This code basically updates the users information on a web service through a call I made.

```
    public ModifyProfileResp ModifyProfile(string n_homeTelephone)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get Login Resp
            LoginResp loginResp = LoginToBetfair("username", "password");

            // Make a BFGS instance
            BFGlobal = new BFGlobalService();

            // Set up the request in [req]
            ModifyProfileReq req = new ModifyProfileReq();
            req.header = new APIRequestHeader();
            req.header.sessionToken = loginResp.header.sessionToken;
            req.homeTelephone = n_homeTelephone;


            // Set up the response in [resp]
            // Here is where Im getting thrown an exception..
            ModifyProfileResp resp = BFGlobal.modifyProfile(req); // <-- Here Im getting thrown an exception

            // return [resp] - which is the response from the call
            // Just trying to print out errror codes
            string mec = resp.minorErrorCode.ToString();
            string ec = resp.errorCode.ToString();

            return resp;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Pretty straightforward, make the request header, call the response, pass in the req and I should get some data back, but I keep getting thrown a exception on this line.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: What exception is thrown? Can you post the message/stack trace?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: You should post the exception so anyone reading your question can have some clue about what the failure was.

Comment: INTERNAL_ERROR,
SoapHeaderException was unhandled.

Comment: @PHP_Guy, sounds like you should take it to [the Betfair developer forum](http://forum.bdp.betfair.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

don't do this:

```
catch (Exception)
{   
    throw;
}
```

It's pointless.  If you don't have the catch the exception will automatically get thrown up a level, which is what you're doing with throw.  Further, if you can't do something with the exception (like retry the request) you're probably better off letting the exception bubble up.

Second, try something like this:

```
catch (SoapHeaderException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

This will catch the specific exception that you're dealing with.  Further, set a breakpoint here on the Debug statement.  You can then browse the details of the exception.  You'll be able to see the stacktrace, inner exceptions and any other data that the thrower of the SoapHeaderException might want you to see.

This information can often be useful when you're debugging, for example, it could say "You forgot to initialize the flux capacitor."

Comment: that's just silly. Not even a @PHP_Guy would forget to initialize the flux capacitor.

Comment: flux capacitor is from the movie back to the future... I SERIOUSLY hope you're either 1. not American or 2. 20 or younger. (@bzlm was saying it was silly to not initialize a flux capacitor...) I saw your name, and figured you might not know about exceptions in C# (in all honesty, I've met a TON of C# developers who didn't know this much about exceptions.)

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an exception from the remote web service.

[SoapHeaderException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheaderexception%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> The exception that is thrown when an XML Web service method is called over SOAP and an exception occurs during processing of the SOAP header.

Likely you're not setting up your headers as the remote service requires. Try to acquire help from the remote side.

Try viewing the [`.InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) for more details.